# Unable to start Android Studio

Tags: android

This was working fine few days back, I don't know what went wrong. Can anyone please help. I am using Windows 8.1

[image]

Comment: You might have to reinstall...

Comment: Did you report it like they asked you to?

Comment: @KristyWelsh - Reinstalling worked. Thanks. But I don't know why this happened. Is there anything I should take care of, so that this error doesn't show up again?

Comment: @poss Yeah, I did. Since that page has many questions without any reply, I thought of asking it here too.

Comment: I see, glad you sorted it out. Hopefully your report will help them to fix it :)